# Is map reduce always distinct from platform as a service?

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce

Does google app engine have a map-reduce within itself or I should use a map-reduce with it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

AppEngine has a readily usable implementation of map reduce available as a separately downloadable component.

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/overview and
https://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce for more details.